# IEnumerable emit as stream?

Tags: c#, stream, ienumerable

Is there a way to take an `IEnumerable<T>` and emit it as a readable stream kinda like this?

```
private void DoTheThing(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
{
    using (var myStream = foos.EmitAsStream(f =>
    {
        var line = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f);
        return line;
    }))
    using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(myStream))
    {
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, there are some problems with this, for example it seems to imply a `StreamWriter` with none specified, but the idea would be that the stream reader would just yield enumerate through the `IEnumerable` under the hood, apply the transform delegate, and pull the results without making any new, potentially large objects in memory.

I have some very large enumerable objects in memory, and I need to push them to external places (like Amazon S3) which accepts a stream.  I really can't afford to build a MemoryStream with the collection and send that; I can spool to disk and read from disk, but I'd prefer not to if I have the option, since it seems like an extra step.

Is this possible?  If it's possible, is it practical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, achieve that by using [TakeWhile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804(v=vs.110).aspx), if I right understood your problem.

Something like :

```
while(..end ..) 
{
   var enumeration = foos.TakeWhile(..line bounds..);
   var stream = StreamFromEnum(enumeration ); //custom implementation
   // stream --> S3
}
```

I presume you have some custom definition of "line", which might be some sort of stride/slice of data from the stream.

[A lazily-evaluated stream wrapper for IEnumerable](https://ryandavis.io/a-lazily-evaluated-stream-wrapper-for-ienumerable/) is a one possible implementation of  `IEnumerable<T>` -> `Stream` conversion.

Comment: That doesn't seem to emit a stream.  I need to end up with a stream to send out.

Comment: you can convert "slice" into the stream of bytes - I guess, bytes is what you need for S3.

Comment: So the point would be to yield enumerate through the `IEnumerable` kinda "on-demand" as the stream spools out, without having a large memory footprint.  S3 client only takes a stream; I don't want a stream for each line, I just want to process the stream input line-by-line

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: but that convertion to stream, which will be eventually sent to the S3, is not cheap. And as much as I understood, `IEnumerable<T>` you dealing with has a lot of data - hence I proposed dealing with it slice by slice. If converting it all at once, and sending to S3 is a feasible solution, you may try it in that way too.

Comment: I'm not opposed to dealing with it slice by slice, I just don't understand how what you are proposing gets me to the point that I can use it?  The `TakeWhile` still seems to output an `IEnumerable`, but the S3 client is passed a `Stream`.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: it reads enumerable stride-by-stride, but requires additional implementation for moving that enumerable into the stream object. see, for example [this](https://ryandavis.io/a-lazily-evaluated-stream-wrapper-for-ienumerable/).

Comment: I think that `EnumerableStream` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Can you put that in your answer?  I'll accept it at that point, thanks

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: ok, did it.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Where you able to consume the stream? I'm getting an exception: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.

Comment: @billybob it seemed to work for me, but I did end up modifying it pretty heavily to fit my needs.

Answer (score 2):

The [EnumerableToStream](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnumerableToStream/) package will do exactly what you ask:

```
using EnumerableToStream;

using (var myStream = foos.Select(f =>
{
    var line = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f);
    return line;
}).ToStream())
```

That ToStream() method is the one that does the magic. If you are interested in the implementation details, have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/bzaar/EnumerableToStream/blob/master/EnumerableToStream/StreamOverEnumerable.cs#L20-L48).